# More than 500 entries per month

Tags: cognito-forms

If I receive more than 500 entries per month, how much do I have to pay?

Is there a sliding scale I can take into account?

Answer (score 2):

I am a developer for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

You can currently use our forms for free with unlimited forms, fields, entries and storage. We do plan to offer paid options in a couple of months for larger organizations with more than 500 entries per month and over 100MB of storage. Your forms will not turn off when these limits are reached and we will make this a smooth transition for our existing customers.

Answer (score 1):

If your form is a payment form, you will pay 1% of what you charge (+the payment processor’s fees). If it isn’t a payment form, it’s free of charge no matter what.

[Source](https://www.cognitoforms.com/pricing).